# 301 Moved Permanently from Axios call

Tags: nginx, axios

My axios call is as follows:

```
export function onixProductTitleByISBN(token, ISBN) {
    const url = `${ONIX_URL}product-title-by-isbn/${ISBN}`;
    let obj = {Authorization:`${token}`}
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: ONIX_PRODUCT_TITLE_LOADING, isLoaded: false});
        return axios.get(url, {headers:obj, followAllRedirects: true})
            .then(({data}) =>{
                dispatch({type: ONIX_PRODUCT_TITLE_SUCCESS, data})
            } )
            .catch((err) => dispatch({type: ONIX_PRODUCT_TITLE_FAILURE, isLoaded: true}))
    }
};
```

This is the resulting api call: 
http://192.168.1.149:8000/api/product-title-by-isbn/9780020100607
if I put that call into Postman, I can get the api to return the value.

When I run this same call with the Axios call it returns:

> 301 Moved Permanently

In nginx in local.conf we have the following code:

```
# first we declare our upstream server, which is our Gunicorn application
upstream onix-api-server {
    # docker will automatically resolve this to the correct address
    # because we use the same name as the service: "onix-api"
    server onix-api:8000;
}

# now we declare our main server
server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        # everything is passed to Gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://onix-api-server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

Instead of returning values it seems to call the same path with a / at the end of it and then gives a 404 not found error

http://192.168.1.149:8000/api/product-title-by-isbn/9781640532632/

I am not sure why it would permanently move this and then call the same path with a / at the end, this seems like it has something to do with the fact that we are using gunicorn and passing that off to nginx. 
[image: multiple calls to same path in devtools]
But I am not sure if this is the reason for it failing and not finding the path. I would expect the first path to return the values Postman gives, but I am not sure why the browser does not return the data. Any help is appreciated.